# Is there a Stack Exchange dedicated to questions about purchasing property / land / homes?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm trying to find a place where I can post a question about purchasing a piece of land and building on it, but I can't seem to find a place for this.

After searching, it seems all of the questions I found about buying a home or land were under the Money stack exchange, but my question is more about the process of buying land / clearing a lot / building on it / what to look out for in those scenarios, rather than about the financial aspect of it.

Is there a stack-exchange site for this kind of material, such as the example below?

> **What to look out for / What questions to ask when purchasing land?**
>
> I'm looking into purchasing a piece of land for the first time, with the intent to build on it.
>
> I've found a parcel / lot that I'd like to purchase. The price for this property seems somewhat low for this area - It's 1.37 acres being sold at just $10,000.
>
> I live somewhat close to houston, so there are similar properties a distance south that are offered at discounts like this because they're on the flood plain and are therefore worthless for building property on, and therefore **i'm concerned about buying a piece of property that may have some sort of issue that is causing the price to be what it is.**
>
> However, I've checked the flood plain maps for this area, and this property is no where near at-risk for such events.
>
> It's a lot that's currently wooded; it's a dense forest.
>
> To build on it, I'm sure I'd have to clear the lot, which would have a cost associated with it; I'm not sure if that's the reason the property is being offered at this low price or not.
>
> I'm sure if I asked the agent "What's wrong with this property?", I'd receive a response of "Nothing! It's fantastic! All of your dreams will come true on this land!", so I'm trying to figure out what due-diligence I need to perform when preparing to purchase a lot.
>
> My question is **what should I be looking for / investigating / what kind of 'red flags' should I be expecting in order to find out if there's an issue with this property?**

Comment: Could you give us the question, that might help us point you in the right direction?

Comment: Perhaps https://law.stackexchange.com/ if you are talking about the legal aspects of it?

Comment: @JakeSymons Updated; added the question

Comment: From a quick google search, some related questions appear on [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) SE, like [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/96919/uneven-floors-red-flag/96937) about read flags. I have asked on [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/home-improvement) to see if question is on-topic.

Comment: This question as written is far too broad for any Stack Exchange site. Some aspects are covered by Personal Finance & Money, some by Law, and I expect a few on Home Improvement.

Comment: Home Improvement has contract and legal questions in our off-topic list. This question would get well into that gray area. What to look for when buying a piece of land gets into opinion based answers and local advice, which are also off-topic. If you can narrow it down to a more specific and factual based question, that might work.

Comment: I think you'd need to ask of which agencies you should contact to vet a property's history of potential miss-use. Be it government, private company, website, etc. The dirt on your dirt so to speak. *something-something land reclamation* ? (Law.SE, indeed) - You have to pick a category of 'red flags' suitable for each site.  At DiY, the best answer would be 'hire a building inspector.' but you would get a lot of other non-sense, because you're asking about more than the house.

Comment: But maybe you should ask at Finance. I think your question boils down to who does an "Environmental inspection" during [due diligence](https://www.cleverism.com/due-diligence-when-buying-real-estate/) which I'd assume is done in conjunction with your bank, who's not going to give you any money until they inspect the property for liens and whatnot. I'd treat rural areas as commercial: "For commercial properties, environmental appraisals begin with a Phase I Environmental Report, which will indicate whether there are serious problems requiring remediation."

Comment: "It's a dense forest."  - Is it currently on fire... ?

Answer (score 3):

[Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) has [159 questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-estate) tagged "[real estate](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-estate)" presently.  I'd suggest there.